# .net [AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied] error when I upload file to s3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3

I want to try to upload file to S3.
I have created an IAM User, and I use that user's accessKey&secretKey.
And I add a policy on my S3 manager:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1465372166563",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1465372163284",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucketName/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I wlways get error:[AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied] 403
when I upload file.

Here is my code:

```
public class S3Controller : Controller
{
    private static readonly string _awsAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];

    private static readonly string _awsSecretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];

    private static readonly string _bucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"];



    public ActionResult UploadToS3()
    {
        return View();
    }




    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadToS3(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        //try
        //{
            IAmazonS3 client;
            using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                var request = new PutObjectRequest()
                {
                    BucketName = _bucketName,
                    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,//PERMISSION TO FILE PUBLIC ACCESIBLE
                    Key = string.Format("UPLOADS/{0}", file.FileName),
                    InputStream = file.InputStream,//SEND THE FILE STREAM

                };

                client.PutObject(request);
            }
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{


        //}
        return View();
    }
}
```